# SQL to pair columns exactly once

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Given a table T with columns X and Y I want to get pairs for columns X and Y but once a value is used in a pair I don't want it to appear again. Example:

```
X   Y
-----
A   1
A   2
A   3
B   1
B   2
B   3
C   4
D   5
D   6
E   5
E   6
```

I want the SQL to output:

```
X   Y
-----
A   1
B   2
C   4
D   5
E   6
```

note that the value of 3 in Y needs to be ignored as there is no other matching value left for it on column X. The order needs to be preserved and the first matching pairs are valid.

Comment: This requires a recursive CTE, if you want a SQL-only solution.  Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm trying to run this in spark SQL so would prefer standard SQL if possible.

Comment: Would A3,B1,C4,D6,E5 also be a valid solution? If not, why not?

Comment: No it wouldn’t as need to pair minimum matching pairs.

Comment: I don't understand this. Your result contains five possible pairs, mine contains five. Are you saying you want to start with the lowest X and find its lowest Y, then get to the next lowest X and find its lowest not yet found Y and so on?

Comment: Yes that’s right.

Comment: What should happen if there is no *lowest unused value* for Y ? (for example: if the`E6` tuple would be absent)

Comment: E6 is guaranteed to exist. I was trying to simplify the question. In the above example I do know that if values of Y exist for a certain X, they will exist together for another value of X. e.g. if there was a value of F5 there would be a value of F6.  but F wouldn't appear in the output.

Comment: Tag the specific database

Comment: My (correct) query ends in an: ERROR:  recursive reference to query "zzz" must not appear within a subquery. You prabably need to refrain to an ugly array  solutiom.

Comment: Well, the recursive+array version works for Postgres. Don't know about  Apache+spark , though

Comment: do you mind sharing your solution so I can test it in spark sql. Thanks.

Comment: In PostgreSQL a clean recursive query is possible, because they have an array data type where you can store the already found X. In other DBMS lacking this, such query would be much more clumsy. I wouldn't do this in SQL, but in the programming language in your app or Website hence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved in pure SQL only with advanced features of specific DB (like Oracle). Also this task is a good example to demonstrate when specific SQL features really do matter.

Below I'm going to demonstrate various approaches using Oracle and Spark.

```
create table t(x, y) as
(select 'A',   1 from dual
union all select 'A',   2 from dual
union all select 'A',   3 from dual
union all select 'B',   1 from dual
union all select 'B',   2 from dual
union all select 'B',   3 from dual
union all select 'C',   4 from dual
union all select 'D',   5 from dual
union all select 'D',   6 from dual
union all select 'E',   5 from dual
union all select 'E',   6 from dual);
```

**1. Oracle `model clause` (Version 10gR1 and later)**

```
SQL> select x, y from
  2  (
  3    select *
  4    from t
  5    model
  6    dimension by (x, y)
  7    measures (0 z)
  8    (z[any, any] order by x, y =
  9     decode(max(z)[x<=cv(x),cv(y)]+max(z)[cv(x),y<=cv(y)],0,1,0))
 10  )
 11  where z = 1;

X          Y
- ----------
A          1
B          2
C          4
D          5
E          6
```

**2. Oracle `recursive with` (Version 11gR2 and later)**

```
with t0 as(select t.*, row_number() over (order by x, y) rn from t)
, r(rn, x, y, z, c, flag) as
(
select t0.rn, t0.x, t0.y, 1, ku$_objnumset(t0.y), 1
from t0
where rn = 1
union all
select t0.rn, t0.x, t0.y
, case when (r.x <> t0.x or flag = 0) and t0.y not member of c then 1 else 0 end
, case when (r.x <> t0.x or flag = 0) and t0.y not member of c then c multiset union ku$_objnumset(t0.y) else c end
, case when (r.x <> t0.x or flag = 0) and t0.y not member of c or (flag = 1 and r.x = t0.x) then 1 else 0 end
from t0
join r on r.rn + 1 = t0.rn
)
select x, y
from r
where z = 1
order by 1;
```

**3. Oracle `recursive with + cross apply` (Version 12cR1 and later)**

```
with
t0 as
 (select t.*, dense_rank() over(order by x) rnk from t),
r(rnk, x, y, c) as
 (select 1, t0.x, min(t0.y), numbers(min(t0.y))
    from t0
   where rnk = 1
   group by t0.rnk, t0.x
  union all
  select r.rnk + 1, t0.x, t0.y, decode(t0.y, null, r.c, r.c multiset union numbers(t0.y))
    from r
   cross apply (select min(t0.x) x, min(t0.y) y
                  from t0
                 where r.rnk + 1 = t0.rnk
                   and t0.y not member of r.c) t0
   where rnk < (select max(rnk) from t0)
 ) cycle x set dummy to 1 default 0
select x, y from r where y is not null order by 1;
```

Oracle has some issues with detecting cycles when cross apply is used in recursive member so dummy column was added to avoid an exception (even though there is no actual cycle).

In all above approaches `y` can be selected only if it has not been selected for previous `X`s. If, however, the goal is to select next min `y` greater than current `y`, then below will also work.

**4. Oracle recursive with and no collections to track allocated `Y`s**

```
with
t0 as
 (select t.*, dense_rank() over(order by x) rnk from t),
r(rnk,y) as
 (
 select 1, min(t0.y)
   from t0
  where rnk = 1
 union all
 select r.rnk + 1,
        nvl((select min(t0.y) y
              from t0
             where r.rnk + 1 = t0.rnk
               and t0.y > r.y), r.y)
   from r
  where rnk < (select max(rnk) from t0)
 )
select x, y
from t0
join (select y, min(rnk) rnk from r group by y) r using (rnk, y) 
order by 1;
```

**5. Oracle `connect by` clause (limit on concatenated string is 4000 chars)**

```
select regexp_substr(m, '~([^#]+)#\d+', 1, level, null, 1) x,
       regexp_substr(m, '~[^#]+#(\d+)', 1, level, null, 1) y
  from (select min(p) keep(dense_rank first order by l desc, rn) m
          from (select rownum rn,
                       level l,
                       sys_connect_by_path(x || '#' || y, '~') p
                  from t
                 start with (x, y) in (select min(x), min(y) from t)
                connect by prior x < x
                       and prior y < y
                       and rownum <= (select count(distinct x) from t)))
connect by regexp_substr(m, '~[^#]+#\d', 1, level) is not null;
```

**And finally Spark + pure functional Scala! (not Spark SQL though)**

```
val q = """
          |select "A" x, 1 y
          |union all select "A", 2
          |union all select "A", 3
          |union all select "B", 1
          |union all select "B", 2
          |union all select "B", 3
          |union all select "C", 4
          |union all select "D", 5
          |union all select "D", 6
          |union all select "E", 5
          |union all select "E", 6
        """
val df = spark.sql(q)

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import scala.annotation.tailrec
```

Transformation for a data frame.

```
def filterRows(df: DataFrame) = {
  val schema = StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("flag", IntegerType))
  implicit val encoder = RowEncoder(schema)

  def getFlag(chk: Boolean, y: Int, a: List[Int]): Integer =
    if (chk && a.forall(_ != y)) 1 else null
  def updAllocated(f: Integer, y: Int, l: List[Int]) = if (f == 1) y :: l else l

  @tailrec def doIt_(iter: Iterator[Row], prevX: String, doCheck: Boolean,
                     allocated: List[Int], res: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] = {
    if (iter.hasNext) {
      val r = iter.next
      val curX: String = r.getAs("x")
      val curY: Int = r.getAs("y")
      val doCheck_ = doCheck || curX != prevX
      val flag = getFlag(doCheck_, curY, allocated)
      doIt_(iter, curX, doCheck_ && flag != 1, updAllocated(flag, curY, allocated),
        res ++ Iterator(Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq :+ flag)))
    } else res
  }

  def doIt(iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] =
    doIt_(iter, "", true, List[Int](), Iterator[Row]())

  df.repartition(1).sortWithinPartitions($"x", $"y").mapPartitions(doIt).
    filter("flag is not null").select($"x", $"y")
}
```

**Test in Spark shell**

```
scala> filterRows(df).show
+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|  A|  1|
|  B|  2|
|  C|  4|
|  D|  5|
|  E|  6|
+---+---+
```

PS. Even most straightforward modification of CTE (option 4 adapted to MSSQL dialect) does not work in MSSQL 2017. Because group functions are not allowed in scalar subqueries in recursive member.

```
GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'r'.
```

After replacing `min(t0.y)` with `top 1 (t0.y)` it throws below exception

```
The TOP or OFFSET operator is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'r'.
```

Option 2, however, can be adapted to MSSQL if we track allocated `Y`s in concatenated string instead of a collection.

Comment: This response is just amazing. :-)